# Microsoft Teams: Bot and Task modules

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I create a bot for Microsoft teams. I use a Task modules for communication with my bot.

Request:

```
{
    "name": "task/fetch",
    "type": "invoke",
    "value": {
            "data": {
                "type": "task/fetch",
                "data": "Click me"
            },
            "context": {
                "theme": "default"
            }
        }
}
```

Response:

```
{
   "task":{
      "type":"continue"
      "value":{
         "url":"http://8364133f.ngrok.io/index.html",
         "title":"Title card",
         "height":"medium",
         "width":"medium",
         "fallbackUrl":"http://8364133f.ngrok.io/index.html"
      },
    }
}
```

And show a popup window with message: 'The task module could not be loaded.'

How can I find out the cause of this error ?

[image: Error]

Comment: Is 8364133f.ngrok.io included in `validDomains` in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, manifest contains this domain. I also create app tab and this tab uses this domain and on tab shows my website

Comment: @bill-bliss-msft  - Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Grinion did you find a solution to this? Getting the same error now

Answer (score 0):

The `url` and `fallbackUrl` must be https. The above is http. Sorry I didn’t catch that earlier, it’s obviously easy to miss.